# apt-get update stuck at "100% [1 Sources 276 kB/277 kB 100%]"

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, updates

I have two servers that are running Ubuntu 14.04.4. When I do `apt-get update`, they both get stuck on

`100% [1 Sources 276 kB/277 kB 100%]` or the same line with a different size(like 199kb).

Packages being searched are not consistent. It searches for `ubuntu-trusty/main Translation-en.` or `trusty-security/main Sources` or others. After a couple of minutes it tries to find it in different repositories, like `at.archive.ubuntu.com` and totally unrelated `apt.dockerproject.org`.

I already read all the related questions and tried various solutions.

**Solutions I've tried:**

1) Delete `/var/lib/apt/lists` and do `apt-get clean`

2) Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to change the main servers.

I really don't know what else I could try. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're running it as sudo, try running it as root instead. Also, I'd try running apt-get upgrade before apt-get update. Are you running the commands over ssh or physically at the 2 servers?

Comment: I'm running the commands over ssh.  Running it as root has no effect. Neither does upgrade before update.

Comment: Try aptitude instead of apt-get. I wasn't able to duplicate this issue. So here is a troubleshooting guide on PackageManager, which has helped me before:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: I have already tried aptitude but it didn't help.

Comment: For me, apt-get clean worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the firewall was blocking the download. So if you have a similar problem, check your firewall settings.